# building menus in fragments in android

Tags: android, android-menu

I am building an application in which each fragments have different menus but the code I am using to add menu but the menu option doesn't actually exists.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    }
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemThatWasClickedId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemThatWasClickedId == R.id.logoutitem) {
        ((tailorDashboard)getActivity()).logoutwork();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Could please try to rephrase your question? Perhaps into more sentences? To make it more clear what causes you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

sir basically i am using this code to make a option menu in fragments i have used android.support.v7.widget.toolbar option to make my custom toolbar. but the code i have already used is not actually making the option menu.

```
`@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    }
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemThatWasClickedId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemThatWasClickedId == R.id.logoutitem) {
        ((tailorDashboard)getActivity()).logoutwork();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}'
```